# Insert query not working in php

Tags: php, sql, echo, sql-insert

I am new to php.I am inserting two integer values in my table using the following code.

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$from = 1;
$to = 3;
$query  = "INSERT INTO 'friendrequests'('from','to') VALUES(1,3)";
echo $query;
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo $result;
// if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{  
  if($result)
 {
    echo "1";
    //exit();
 }
 else
 {
    echo "0";
//    exit();
 }
}
```

but echo also not at all printing any values.just am getting 0 as response.Please help me to solve.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you selected specific database? Try to do "INSERT INTO friendrequests (from, to) VALUES(1,3)"

Comment: if you echo $result; you will get true(1) or false(0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `` ` `` around column_name and table_name rather than `'`(single quote)

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO `friendrequests`(`from`,`to`) VALUES(1,3)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error table names should be put into `` marks.

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO `friendrequests` (`from`,`to`) VALUES(1,3)";
```

Also to check if query worked you should use [mysql_affected_rows()](https://www.php.net/mysql_affected_rows)(when you click on this link look at the red warning box and read it)

> **mysql_affected_rows()** - Get the number of affected rows by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query associated with link_identifier.

Consider changing your db engine to mysqli or pdo because mysql_* functions will be removed and they are depracated.